# Question marks when using czech characters in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have the problem that some czech characters can not be displayed/printed properly in python. No matter which of the following version I use I always get a "?" when trying to print the character.

```
s1 = "č"
s2 = u"\u010D"
s3 = unicode(u'\u010D', "utf-8")
s4 = unicode('č', "utf-8")
```

What am I missing? I can print the characters ýýááíů but not ěščřřžž.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you tried to use symbol and diacritical mark instead of this?

Comment: >>> test = '\u0063\u030c'
>>> print(test)
č
>>>

Answer (score 1):

Use combining caron with your chars instead of using solid char. Atleast this displays correctly [in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT5qb.jpg):

```
>>> test = '\u0065\u030c , \u0073\u030c , \u0063\u030c , \u0072\u030c , \u007a\u030c'
>>> print(test)
ě , š , č , ř , ž
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Max.For test = '\u0065\u030c , \u0073\u030c , \u0063\u030c , \u0072\u030c , \u007a\u030c' I get: \u0065\u030c , \u0073\u030c , \u0063\u030c , \u0072\u030c , \u007a\u030c. For test = u'\u0065\u030c , \u0073\u030c , \u0063\u030c , \u0072\u030c , \u007a\u030c' I get: e? , s? , c? , r? , z?. I am using Python 2.5.

Comment: @Luigi04 Actually i use Python 3.5.2, maybe thats why our results vary. Let me test this with 2.5, and if i will get the solution, ill tell you.